The Unity button does not respond
I am trying to develop a game in Unity. A respawn button is displayed on the GameOver screen. But it does not respond.
Unity interface with the button
Here is the image of the button in the Inspector
The code should actually run so that you are revived. However, the button did not react
    public void Respwan()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);
    }

This is the Code

Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take a [tour] and see [ask]. Note that StackOverflow is an English only site.

Ensure your button isn't overlayed by another UI item "stealing" the cursor raycast

which UI system, if old  do you have an event system, do any other buttons on the screen work?

Thank you for translating your question. Unfortunately, it still appears to lack a [mre]. Please provide enough information so we can reproduce, or at least fully understand, the issue.

Did you assign the button to execute the Respwan method? Can you also provide a screenshot, showing your button's inspector window

It could be that you are calling the wrong function because Respawn() is spelled Respwan() in the code snippet. Try watching https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tBj-FWcIwYw because it is a good example on how to fix your problem. Another potential bug could be in the actual Unity instpector. Make sure that your buttonClick function is being called when you click the button. You can change this in the Inspector prefs. If you need more help, then maybe try putting more screenshots of your code and your game and also the inspector tab on the UI element.
